# how to drop nan values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Sample data:

```
      WN    TOW    Azimuth  Elevation   S4_SIG1 S4_SIG2 TEC
0   2138    432060  289           38    0.087   0.075   16.083
1   2138    432060  37             5    0.175   nan     22.237
2   2138    432060  42            39    0.058   nan     11.188
3   2138    432060  283            6    0.210   nan     19.156
4   2138    432060  23            60    0.054   nan     14.448
```

I am using

```
df4=df3.dropna(how='any')
df4
```

But then it is returning same dataframe. I tried `subset=['S4_SIG2']`still it didnt worked out.SOS!!

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. `df.dropna()` correctly gives me a dataframe with just row 0. Are you sure they're true nans and not text?

Comment: What's the output of `type(df.iat[1, 5])`? (That should be the first nan cell in the `S4_SIG2` column)

Comment: ```numpy.float64```

Answer (score 0):

```
#change to type float
df3 ['WN'] = df3['WN'].astype(float)
df3 ['TOW'] = df3['TOW'].astype(float)
df3 ['Azimuth'] = df3['Azimuth'].astype(float)
df3 ['Elevation'] = df3['Elevation'].astype(float)
df3 ['S4_SIG1'] = df3['S4_SIG1'].astype(float)
df3 ['S4_SIG2'] = df3['S4_SIG2'].astype(float)
df3 ['TEC'] = df3['TEC'].astype(float)
df3.dropna()
```

Comment: I added an answer that simplifies this process, and keeps columns that should be `int` as `int` instead of upcasting to `float`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix a DataFrame that should be numeric, but that's currently object typed by doing:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```